# Show posts from last 3 years in posts page

Tags: posts

I have created a page called Blog and selected it as posts page. What I need here is, I don't want to show all posts but I need to show only posts from 2015 to till date.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: What did you try so far? Please post your current relevant code.

Comment: It's been a while since I've done this, but review [query_posts()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/query_posts/) and [WP_Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query). You should be able to set date/time requirements before you call your post loop.

Answer (score 0):

**You should adapt it to fit your needs, e.g. (not tested) :**
// Create a new filtering function that will add our where clause to the query

```
function filter_where( $where = '' ) {
   $where .= " AND post_date > '" . date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-1 year')) . "'";
return $where;
}<br>

add_filter( 'posts_where', 'filter_where' );
$query = new WP_Query( $query_string );<br>
remove_filter( 'posts_where', 'filter_where' );
```

Comment: Why not use the `date_query` argument in `WP_Query` ?

Comment: Yes you can use data_query arguments with different params acc. to your need [codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Date_Parameters)